# Polynomial Regression bad plot

Tags: python, regression

I'm new to this whole thing so i've been searching a lot for a solution and reading blogs etc. but to no avail, if you could please explain the problem along with the solution i would greatly appreciate it.

[![][1]][1]

code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pead_csv(

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)



}

d
    return
viz_polymonial()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do the fitting of polynomial features twice, is it your intended use?

The described problem originates in the fact that `plt.plot(X, Y)` joins with lines `(X[0], Y[0])` with `(X[1], Y[1])`, `(X[1], Y[1])` with `(X[2], Y[2])`, etc. The order matters, if you shuffle X and Y, you will get a different plot. Here your points are unordered, you need to sort them to get a smoother plot.

```
def viz_polymonial():
    plt.scatter(X.iloc[:, 1], Y, color='red')
    data = list(zip(X, pol_reg.predict(poly_reg.transform(X)))
    # sort data by X and unpack
    sorted_X, sorted_Y = **sorted(data)
    plt.plot(sorted_X, sorted_Y, color='blue')
    plt.xlabel('Age. Annual income')
    plt.ylabel('Spending Score')
    plt.show()
    return
viz_polymonial()
```

If you do minimal reproducible example, I will test it on my machine.